# Fastboot is not providing a token when trying to unlock HTC One M9

Tags: rooting, fastboot, bootloader, htc-one

I am trying to unlock my HTC One M9 following the instructions on the HTCdev website. When I get to the part where you're supposed to obtain the identifier token, it doesn't give me any errors, but it also doesn't give the token. I have the phone booted in 'download mode' (As far as I can tell from the HTCdev website, this is the equivalent of fastboot mode for everything M9 and later. There is no actual fastboot mode in the bootloader).

Below is what I get when I type in 'fastboot oem get_identifier_token'.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot oem get_identifier_toke
n
...
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] : /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/frp
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] Last Byte is 0X00, disable unlock
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] oem unlock Turn Off!
OKAY [  0.059s]
finished. total time: 0.064s
```

Do you have any ideas about what I'm missing here?

Comment: Maybe you could try the command 'fastboot oem unlock'. Maybe that'll work?

Answer (score 4):

```
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] : /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/frp
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] Last Byte is 0X00, disable unlock
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] oem unlock Turn Off!
```

This means that you need to enable Developer Options in your phone's Settings (go to About and tap the version number repeatedly), then go into those options and check Enable OEM Unlock.  This setting prevents a thief (who doesn't know your device password and thus can't change this setting) from unlocking your bootloader, flashing a new ROM, and gaining use of the phone.

See http://www.droid-life.com/2014/11/04/fyi-android-5-0-introduces-enable-oem-unlock-option-in-developer-options/

Note that not every phone has this setting: only those that can be unlocked by fastboot in the first place do. This answer applies to the phone in the question and other phone vendors that allow their bootloaders to be unlocked. Not all vendors do.

Comment: Just to add that on some devices (I had it on my HTC U11 Life), the "Enable OEM Unlock" option works for one reboot only. If you rebooted into the normal operation mode instead of "Download Mode" by mistake, you will need to enable the option again.